# How to get point's coordinate along plane's normal vector?

Tags: 3d, java-3d

I have one plane which it has normal vector(p,q,r) and center(x,y,z). I want to get only point1's coordinate (not both point1 and point2) which is away 10 meter along plane's normal from center.

I am using JAVA to automatically solve it.
[image]

Comment: center+normal=point, center-normal = other point

Comment: @ huseyin tugrul buyukisik. could you please tell me more? how can I do it?

Comment: do you have surface normal and surface center?

Comment: What is `point2`? Is it the origin?  Is it the center (x,y,z)?

Comment: @ huseyin tugrul buyukisik. yes. I have normal (p,q,r) and center (x,y,z)

Comment: @Peter O. I edited just now. center is the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure the normal (p, q, r) is normalized:

```
double length = Math.sqrt(p*p + q*q + r*r);
if(length!=0){
  p/=length;
  q/=length;
  r/=length;
}
```

Then add 10 times the normal to the point's center;

```
double p1x = centerX + p*10.0;
double p1y = centerY + q*10.0;
double p1z = centerZ + r*10.0;
```

Note that as it is, your question is currently ambiguous; it doesn't show the
direction the normal is pointing; there are two possibilities: the normal can point
either forward (toward point1) or back (toward point2). I assume here that
the normal points forward.

Comment: You can use Vector3d.normalize() (from Vecmath as the original poster uses Java) to normalize the normal and then Tuple3d.add(Tuple3d,Tuple3d).